# Heap allocation of struct without copy, move and default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, new-operator

I have a struct that cannot be neither copied nor moved, nor it has a default constructor:

```
struct Data {
  int a;

  Data(const Data&) = delete;
  Data& operator=(const Data&) = delete;

  Data(Data&&) = delete;
  Data& operator=(Data&&) = delete;

  Data(int i):
    a{i}
  {}
};
```

I would like to allocate in the heap an array of these struct constructing all of them with the same constructor. I managed to accomplish this in the following way:

```
Data* ppd = (Data*)::operator new(10 * sizeof(Data));

for (auto p = ppd; p < ppd + 10; ++p)
  new(p) Data{45};
```

however I'm very unsatisfied with that. Obviously I have a look to [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), but I could not find what I was looking for.

Do you have any suggestion to accomplish my task in a more expressive way?

Comment: *"however I'm very unsatisfied with that...."* **Why?** Does it not work or do you see something wrong with it.

Comment: It seems triky and not so expressive in C++. At least to me.

Comment: You explicitly made a hard to use class, it's always going to be tricky to get around that.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't do... I have to manage to use it :(

Comment: This has the smell of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is your task or assignment? Where did you get it from? Where did you get the class from?

Comment: Is `10` known at compile time?

Comment: @Artyer: no, it is not.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: the `Data` class is defined in a library that is used in several other places. I do know it has some flow, but changing it would mean to at least test all the other application that are relying on it. Unfortunately I do not have the time. Of course if I had I would rewrite all of them, I would really love to!

Comment: if objects of that class are hard to put into array, then maybe just maybe they arent meant to be put into an array. On the other hand, if the obstacles are only coincidentally, and the author didnt actually want to make it difficult to construct an array, maybe its worth a change request. What is `Data` actually?

Comment: I think it has simply been bad-designed.

Comment: i mean, how are you supposed to work with `Data` generally? Not being able to copy nor move is a rather big restriction that reflects in code using the class (not only when constructing an array)

Comment: It is something has the unique pointer semantic. The move constructor and assignment in principle should be there...

Comment: "I think it has simply been bad-designed." then your code is totally fine. Doing something awkward should look awkward :D Seriously, creating an array of this type is complicated, so code that would look simple would be a lie. Your code very cleany expresses what it does, it allocates memory then creates objects in that memory.

Comment: Quick solutions are using `std::make_unique<Data>(45);` or an `std::optional<Data>` but if you want zero overhead you need to use placement new or `construct_at`. I think the best solution here is to wrap your poorly behaved class in PIMPL wrapper, just a class with a `unique_ptr<Data>` member which can introduce move semantics and default construction and simplifies the creation of a `Data`.

Answer (score 3):

Is it a possibility for you, to use `std::list` instead of an array type?

Some containers like `std::vector` won't work because the data might get reallocated, which is not possible, as the move constructor is deleted. `std::list`'s data will not get reallocated.

Because `push_back` uses some default constructors as well `emplace_back` could be used instead to call your custom constructor.

```
std::list<Data> list;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    list.emplace_back(45);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use macro and boost as shown below:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum.hpp>
#define Create_B_List(...) {__VA_ARGS__}
#define Repeat(P, A, X) X
#define Create(Count, Value) Create_B_List(BOOST_PP_ENUM(Count, Repeat, Value))

int main()
{  
    Data *p = new Data[]Create(10, 45);     
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q48hGq77P)